# Django ORM exclude fails

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm, psql

I have some problems with my query - with filter() it's ok but with exclude() doesn't work.
My models:

```
class Dictionary(DateTimeModel):
    base_word = models.ForeignKey(BaseDictionary, related_name=_('dict_words'))
    word = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    version = models.ForeignKey(Version)

class FrequencyData(DateTimeModel):
    word = models.ForeignKey(Dictionary, related_name=_('frequency_data'))
    count = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, related_name=_('frequency_data'), null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name=_('frequency_data'))
    user_ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_checking = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_checked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And I want to get some words from Dictionary where whose frequencies are not from some user

```
Dictionary.objects.prefetch_related('frequency_data').filter(frequency_data__user=1)[:100] - OK

Dictionary.objects.prefetch_related('frequency_data').exclude(frequency_data__user=1)[:100] - processor up to 100% and loading
```

Without prefetch_related the same. What is wrong with exclude?

**EDIT**
Dictionary db tabel - 120k rows
FrequencyData - 160k rows

**EDIT2**
psql(9.6.6)

Comment: please show `Dictionary.objects.prefetch_related('frequency_data').exclude(frequency_data__user=1).count()`

Comment: This same - still waiting... 
Dictionary table has about 120k records and FrequencyData 160k.

I check with filter() and count() - it was 120k - so exclude should show 0

Comment: try `qs=Dictionary.objects.prefetch_related('frequency_data').exclude(frequency_data__user=1).count(); print(qs.query)`  and then in the `./manage.py dbshell` try to execute the result of print.

Comment: For this request shell the same like above - it's hangs. I try it locally and get 
`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'query'`

Next I try locally:
`from django.db import connection
qs=Dictionary.objects.prefetch_related('frequency_data').exclude(frequency_data__user=1).count()
print(connection.queries)`
and my result: https://pastebin.com/ZMG0StN1

Comment: cool but why there 3 times query?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot reset_queries. Now it's only one: https://pastebin.com/ebfyHqdw

Comment: and the query is executed in `'time': '0.039'` yes?

Comment: Yes, but on my computer (locally).  On the server (shared hosting) psql hangs. It's strange. Is it problem with postgres?

Comment: try to execute the `sql` inside the `plsql`

Comment: I tried and it hangs for 15 minutes :/ Locally works fine

Comment: simple `count` works 15 min? if yes do `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` in the psql for the select and create new question with postgres tag.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610415/postgresql-count-query-takes-too-much-time

Comment: try the select writed in the comment to your new question